# Retrieve seconds, along with date and time in CMD?

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I'm trying to ping an IP, and receive the time date and seconds to a file.
I'm running the command `date/t&&time/t&&ping`  That gives me 09:50 PM and Sat 05/25/13, but is there anyway I can get like :45 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo %date% %time% & ping stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `time/t` use `echo %TIME%`.

By the same means instead of `date/t` you can use `echo %DATE%`